# Compute the conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

> Let $X$ be a random variable. If we toss a coin and get "head" $X\sim U(0,1)$
>   , else $X\sim U(1,2)$.  Define
>   $G_1=\sigma(\{X^{-1}(1/2)\},\{X^{-1}(3/2)\})$ and
>   $G_2=\sigma(\{X^{-1}(A):A\subseteq [1/2,3/2],:A \text{ Borelset}\})$.
>   Compute $\mathbb{E}(X|G_1), \mathbb{E}(X|G_2)$.

My try:

$$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|G_1)\mathbb{1}_{\{X^{-1}(1/2)\}}) = \mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_{\{X^{-1}(1/2)\}}) = 1/2 \mathbb{P}(X=1/2) = 0$$
and it is similar for $X^{-1}(3/2)$, that's why $$\mathbb{E}(X|G_1)=0.$$

Moreover we have $$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|G_2)\mathbb{1}_{\{X^{-1}(A):A\subseteq [1/2,1]\}}) = \mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_{\{X^{-1}(A):A\subseteq [1/2,1]\}}) = \frac{1+1/2}{2} = \frac{3}{4}$$
and $$\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X|G_2)\mathbb{1}_{\{X^{-1}(A):A\subseteq [1,3/2]\}}) = \mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{1}_{\{X^{-1}(A):A\subseteq [1,3/2]\}}) = \frac{1+3/2}{2} = \frac{5}{4},$$ so we have $$\mathbb{E}(X|G_2)=1/2 * 3/4 + 1/2 * 5/4= 1.$$

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me if it is correct or if there is an error somewhere.